# How do I evaluate this integral surface?

Tags: integration, surfaces, surface-integrals

I want to evaluate $$\int_R(-x^2y \ dx + xy^2 \ dy)$$
where R is the closed curve of the semicircle $x^2 + y^2 = a^2, y>0$ along the segment $(-a,a)$ of the x-axis, by first expressing it in the form of $$\int\int_D\frac{\partial Q}{\partial X} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dx\ dy = \int\int y^2 - x^2 dx \ dy$$

I have differentiated the equation above to get the form below, and I believe the limits should be :$$\int^a_{-a} \int^{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}_0 y^2 + x^2 dy \ dx$$

Is this the correct way? But If I integrate in this manner, I get an expression like $$[\frac{y^3}{3} + x^2y]$$ which when I substitute the limits in, I cannot integrate further. Is this the right way to do it?

Here is what I get after continuing the integration:

$$\int^a_{-a} (a^2-x^2)^\frac{1}{2} (\frac{a^2-x^2}{3} + x^2) \ dx$$

This seems not possible to be integrated because even after doing integration by-parts, there will always be that power of half that I cannot remove....

Comment: No, you made a couple of pretty serious mistakes in your setup -- order of integration, antidifferentiating simple polynomials. You have the right idea, I think. If you go back and fix the basic things and you're still confused I'll help.

Comment: Remember integrating $y^2+x^2$ over $x$ produces: $xy^2+(1/3)x^3$.

Comment: I have seen the typo and made the changes. The above was actually what I got but couldn't continue further (mistakenly typed what I did not solve for just now).

Comment: However, I don't get why you mean that the order of integration is wrong. Aren't the limits the correct?

Comment: Which variable runs from $-a$ to $a$? -- After you work out the limits of integration more carefully, though, you can do the integral! You could even do the one you have above. Just be brave.

Comment: I see what you are saying, and x is (-a, a). The part where I got stuck I have edited and put it above

Comment: Good. Does $a^2-x^2$ look like a familiar pattern suggesting a method of integration that's not by parts?

Comment: It looks like it's eligible for $tan^{-1}x$ differentiation but then it's not at the denominator, so what can I do?

Comment: (i) that's not the $tan^{-1}$ pattern. (ii) Doesn't matter whether it's in the denominator or not. You can always do the sub and see what you come up with.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what you are saying, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)
$$ \oint_{R}-x^2 y\,dx + xy^2\,dy = \iint_{D}\left(x^2+y^2\right)\,dx\,dy $$
where $D$ is the region given by $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$ and $y\geq 0$.
 By switching to polar coordinates the RHS turns into
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{a}\rho^3\,d\rho\,d\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}a^4.$$